# Need to add submit button that will email the form's data to me

Tags: html, forms, email, web, submit

Here is my "form" http://www.confidentialpatient.com/js/index.html

I need to add a few things to this:

- The person, once finished adding "items," clicks "NEXT"
- On the next page, a summary of the items selected on the previous page is given (in a list format). Basically, this is a confirmation page
- They are then able to click "SUBMIT," in which this form data is emailed to me.

I know this might be a lot, but I'd greatly appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this without a server-side scripting language. The few choices you have are PHP, ASP.NET, PERL or Python.

For your reference, I have mentioned a test script along with PHP code to submit a form with only one field and then receive that information on the next page and then display it to the user in an h2 tag.

Code for page 1:

```
<form method="post" action="page2.html">
   <h1>This is a test form</h1>
   <label>Enter your full name</label>
   <input type="text" name="fullname" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

Code for page 2 (Receiving page):

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['fullname'];
?>
<h2>You submitted name is: <?php echo $name; ?> </h2>
```